# Markdown で #見出し で「C#」と表示させたい

Tags: markdown

Typora というMarkdownエディタで、ドキュメントを書いているのですが
見出し行に「C#」と表示させたいのですが 期待通りに表示されません。

`###C#` と書くと 「C」と表示されます。
エスケープするのかと思い `###C\#` とかくと 「C\」と表示されます。

行頭に「#」は書かずに、次の行に「===」を書けば表示は出来るのですが、ドキュメント内の書式の一貫性が失われるので、出来れば、行頭に「#」を書くスタイルで実現したいと思っています。どのようにすれば実現できるか教えてください。

SOでも同じ結果になるようなので、以下、実際に書いてみます。

```
###C#
```

#### C

```
###C\#
```

#### C\

```
C#
===
```

## C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
### 見出し
```

の他に

```
### 見出し ###
```

があるため、行末 `#` がこれに反応しているのかもしれません。

```
### C# ###
```

#### C#

でどうでしょうか？ また行末が`#`でなければいいのであれば

```
### C#<space>
```

#### C#

でもいけるかもしれません。

Comment: Typoraだと `### C# ###` で期待通りに表示できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 6):

HTML の文字実体参照を使って

```
### C&#035;
```

#### C#

とするのはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 残念ながら Typora だと表示できませんでした。多分アプリが対応してないだけだと思いますが、こういう解決方法もあったんですね。ありがとうございます。

Comment: Typoraでは使えなかったとのことですが、別の観点で、Markdownの実装によっては見出しに対してリンクを提供するものもあります。見出しに文字実体参照を使用してしまうと変なリンクが生成されてしまうものもあるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

参考: [How to escape the (hash) # sign in a Github markdown header? (backslash is not working) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196555)

上記リンク先の通り、github(gist)だと`### C\#`でも所望の結果が得られましたが、Typoraだと駄目で、(他の方の回答と被りますが)次のように書けば表示されました。

```
### C# #
```

解釈の違い、いわゆる方言による差異ですね。

ちなみにgithubなら↓もOKです(がTyporaはNGでした)。

```
<h3>C#</h3>
```